# LINQ - find between lowest and highest string

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq

I would like to find string numbers between "0000" and "9999" inside larger strings
from "qwt0000abc" to "qwt9999abc".

MSSQL where id between "qwt0000abc" and "qwt9999abc"

How I would write the same LINQ query?

```
var selectedOrders = orders.Where(f => f.Id between "qwt0000abc" and "qwt9999abc");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your code sample code is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want rows with that same prefix and suffix, then just replace `between` like this:

```
var selectedOrders = orders.Where(f => f.Id.CompareTo("qwt0000abc") >= 0 && f.Id.CompareTo("qwt9999abc") < 0).ToList() ;
```

And if this is EF you can perhaps use Like:

```
var selectedOrders = orders.Where(f => EF.Functions.Like(f.Id, "qwt[0-9][0-9][0-9]abc")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var selectedOrders = arr.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, ".*[0-9]{4}.*"));
```

or this, if you need exactly `qwt` prefix and `abc` suffix.

```
var selectedOrders = arr.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, "qwt[0-9]{4}abc"));
```

`.*` here is any literal any number of times(include zero), `[0-9]{4}` is digit between 0 and 9, exactly 4 digits.

Comment: That's not going to work if this is EF and needs to be translated to SQL.

Comment: A possible alternative, but instead of introducing regex, how about using just linq and explain that?